# How to implement sitelink search box

Tags: json, scripting

I'm trying to implement the sitelink search box in my site, but so far its not working, this is my code in the homepage and even in my search page

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> { "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/process/buscador.html?search={search_term}", "query-input": "required name=search_term" } } </script>
```

can anyone tell me why is not working?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I also recently implemented it for www.proptiger.com. Searching a term is taking user to my site's search page. But the issue is that i am not seeing suggestion in the sitelink search box, only one suggestion is coming which I typed. So does it mean i have to wait for some days.

Comment: Well, i checked your site, and you have similar code to mine... the point is if you add a query to your url, it show result, same as mine too...
http://www.proptiger.com/filters?q=sales
should that url be dinamyc? something like

http://www.proptiger.com/filters?q=DinamycVariableHere

Comment: hey Jaciel - any progress here. I am trying to find solution, but there is none. Please let me know if you finds it. the url is dynamic. <DynamicVariableHere> will be replaced with the search terms. I read somewhere that it depends on the traffic on your site, which make sense also as more user visiting to your site will use search more. That is google want to facilitate here I guess.

Comment: hello again, sorry for the delay, i quit my job for a long time, so i couldnt check the answer, ill try to implement this search box again. thanks for help